# Redux Store not connecting in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, redux

I'm writing a React Chrome Extension that injects content into multiple areas of various pages, and also has a popup for user login

Within my render function, have the following:

```
    <Provider store={store}>
        { RowDiv() }
        { isChromeExt() }
    </Provider>
```

In those functions, I render React Portals like so:

```
function RowDiv() {
    if(window.location.href.split('/')[2] === 'foo') {
        const viewport = document.getElementsByClassName('top-nav-links-container')[0];
        const app = document.createElement('div');
        app.id = 'ml-row';
        viewport.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', app);
        return (<Portal element={ document.getElementById('ml-row')}><Row /></Portal>)
    }
}

function isChromeExt() {
    if(window.location.href.includes("chrome-extension://")) {
        return (
            <Portal element={ document.getElementById('root')}>
                <Dashboard>
                    <Login />
                </Dashboard>
            </Portal>
        )
    }
}
```

In my Login component which is within a Chrome popup, when a user logs in I dispatch their token and user data `this.props.dispatch(login(token.access_token, user));`

This calls my action, which calls my reducer.  These do get triggered:

```
export function login(jwt, user) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({jwt, user});
    return {
        type: LOGIN,
        jwt,
        user,
    };
}

---

if (action.type === authTypes.LOGIN) {
    console.log("action Login")
    return {
        token: action.jwt,
        user: action.user,
    };
}
```

In my Row component, I use connect, and mapStateToProps:

```
function mapStateToProps({ user }) {
        console.log(user);
    return {
        token: user.token,
        user: user.user,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Row);
```

The issue I am having though is that when a user logs in, it does not seem to trigger in my Row component.

If I reload the page where Row is injected, the props are there.

Does anyone know why I can't get redux to trigger in my Row component?